# Running a NodeJS app automaticaly at the start up

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, autostart

I have a little NodeJS app that accesses to a MongoDB database and takes some data in order to be displayed in an index.html file. I run it on an Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 OS on a Raspberry Pi B+

I run the NodeJS app with the line:

```
node /routeofmyapp/index.js
```

Then the server starts up and I can go to the index.html file and check the displayed data.

The next thing I want to do in the project is executed automatically the `index.js` at the start-up of the system without having to launch the console terminal.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look for `systemd` service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc` file.

Go to the last line of the script and add:

```
echo Running at boot 
sudo node /routeofmyapp/index.js
```

Then save and reboot RPi:

`sudo reboot`

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But I have to manually launch the console terminal in order to run it. Is there a way to launch automatically the console terminal at the start up?

Comment: Since you've added `sudo node /routeofmyapp/index.js` command to `.bashrc` script and rebooted your RPi you don't have to open terminal and launch nodejs app manually. It should be launched at RPi booting by `.bashrc`  script. Or try the same modification but for `/etc/rc.local` file. For more details look [link 1](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/) [link 2](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup/all)